# Vb.net Nickname an object?

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
Dim ThisThing as ThisThingToolStripMenuItem.Text
```

So i can later in the code just do ThisThing = "whatever" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that won't work, but you can assign `ThisThingToolStripMenuItem` to a variable with a smaller name, but you still have to reference it as `ThisThing.Text`.

You can also use a delegate defined with a lambda expression:

```
Action<string> setter = (string s) => ThisThingToolStripMenuItem.Text = s;

...

setter("whatever");
```

In VB.Net:

```
Dim Setter = Sub(s) ThisThingToolStripMenuItem.Text = s

...

Setter("whatever")
```

Comment: This is what i wanted, thanks. Was trying to get some neatness in my code.

Comment: on the other hand, when i issue this in form1, it says Expression is not a method when i use it in a sub.

Comment: @Joseph R - can you post your code as an edit to your question?  Also, what version of VB.Net are you using?

Answer (score 0):

A variable has to be a type so the best you can do is something like this...

```
Dim objYourShorterName As New ToolStripMenuItem

'Where 1 is the particular index of the ToolStripMenuItem you wish
'the variable to reference.
objYourShorterName = ToolStrip1.Items(1)

'You still have to use the Text property.
objYourShorterName.Text = "Blah"
```

You can write a Sub Procedure to do it for you too.

```
Private Sub ShorterName(ByVal strText As String)

   ToolStrip1.Items(1).Text = strText

End Sub
```

Then to change the text...

```
ShorterName("New Text")
```